# clear: right also does clear: left?? Strange floating behaviour

Tags: html, css, css-float

It seems that `clear: right` causes also `clear: left` for all consecutive floats! See
http://jsfiddle.net/Mx7zu/11/ or this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div { margin: 16px; width: 200px; height: 130px; border: solid red 1px; }
#right1 { float: right; }
#right2 { float: right; clear: right; }
#left1, #left2 { float: left; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="right1">Right 1</div>
<div id="right2">Right 2</div>
<div id="left1">Left 1</div>
<div id="left2">Left 2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would expect the divs left1 and left2 to be at the top, at the same level as right1! This only happens when I place the div with `clear: right` (right2) as the last one:

```
<div id="right1">Right 1</div>
<div id="left1">Left 1</div>
<div id="left2">Left 2</div>
<div id="right2">Right 2</div>
```

Can you please explain this strange behaviour? Thanks in advance! Tested in FF 9.0.1.

Comment: You can't assign clear and float to the same element.

Comment: @Jaa-c, why? What will then happen? I see I can do it and it works - the div right2 is both floating and clearing.

Comment: @Jaa-c: That is not true. A floated element cannot clear itself, but it can clear previous floats, which is what the `clear` property does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the browser as, by default, laying out the page from left to right and top to bottom.

Initially the starting point for content is at the top, left hand side.

The `float:right` of `#right1` shrink wraps the div and moves it to the right side. The space to the left of it is available for other content.

The `float:right` of `#right2` shrink wraps the div and attempts to moves it to the right side as well. But the `clear:right` stops it from going next to the `#right1` div. So the starting point for content to be placed is moved down until the `#right2` div can be successfully placed. It's then placed on the right.

The `#left1` div is then placed. The `float:left` shrink wraps the div and attempts to place it at the starting point for content which is now directly to the left of `#right2`. Since the space to the left of `#right2` is large enough to contain `#left1`, that's where `#left1` is placed.

Similarly, the space to the left of `#right2` and to the right of `#left1` is large enough to accommodate `#left2`, that's where `#left2` is placed.

Comment: Alohci, but the `clear: right` should affect only the right side, not both! Otherwise I would use `clear: both`! That's the unclear thing I'm asking about! I placed the comment directly at place in your post.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what `clear` does. CSS 2.1 says: [This property indicates which sides of an element's box(es) may not be adjacent to an earlier floating box.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control). i.e. It doesn't stop following content from being alongside it, it stops the element from being alongside preceding content.

Comment: @Tomas - That is, the `clear:right` stops `#right2` having `#right1` to its right. Nothing else.

Comment: Alohci, that's not true! If the `clear: right` would only affect `#right2`, I'd be happy. But it also affects `#left1` and `#left2`. Do you now understand what I mean?

Comment: @Tomas - `#left1` and `#left2`'s positions are affected by the movement of the starting point for content, which is a consequence of the positioning of `#right2`, as per the description in my answer. See http://jsfiddle.net/Mx7zu/14/ for an example that might help you understand.

Comment: Thanks Alohci. This probably means I have to enclose the left and right divs in a big div to assure independent floating behaviour. Which is the solution I finally used.