# Floats not being cleared

Tags: html, css

I posted a similar question last week when having a problem and wasn't sure if I could re-ask in the same question or not so I have created a new one just incase.

I've got two columns, one floated left and one floated right, and I am using clear:both to clear the floats but it is not working. I have checked to make sure all my DIV tags are closed and they are (this was the issue last time) and moving the clear:both to different parts but still it decides not to work. Code is below but if you would like to see what it looks like it can be seen here http://www.richardawarner.co.uk/portfoliov2

Any help is appreciated.

HTML

```
<div id="sectiontwowrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>About Me</h1>
        </div><!--Header-->

        <div id="contentwrapper">
            <div id="aboutmeleft">
                <h3>About Me</h3>
                <br>
                <a>My name is <strong>Richard Warner</strong> and I am a young web designer from Birmingham, United Kingdom. I have recently graduated from Manchester Metropolitan University having studied BSc(Hons) Multimedia Computing. Whilst having an interest in studying different aspects to computers, it was here where I developed a passion for web design. I have learnt various languages such as HTML, CSS and PHP aswell as experienced using Adobe Photoshop, Adobe Dreamweaver and other Adobe products.</a>

                <p>
                    <h3>Skills and Expertise</h3>
                    <br>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>HTML and CSS</a></li>
                            <li><a>PHP</a></li>
                            <li><a>MySQL</a></li>
                            <li><a>Wordpress</a></li>
                            <li><a>Adobe Photoshop</a></li>
                            <li><a>Adobe Dreamweaver</a></li>
                        </ul>

            </div><!-- About me left -->

            <div id="aboutmeright">
                <h3>Hobbies</h3>
                <br>
                <a>Hobbies will appear here</a>

                <p>
                    <h3>My CV</h3>
                    <br>
                        <a>You can download my CV by clicking here.</a>
            </div><!-- About Me right -->


        </div><!--Content Wrapper -->


    </div><!--Section Two Wrapper -->
    <div class="clear"></div>


    <div id="sectionthreewrapper">
        this line should be underneath this sections border line below
    </div> <!--Section three wrapper -->
```

CSS

```
#sectiontwowrapper {

position: relative;
top: 100px;
min-height: 550px;
min-width: 960px;
text-align: left;
border: solid 1px #000;

#contentwrapper {

width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
}

#aboutmeleft {

width: 450px;
height: 400px;
/*border: 1px solid #000;*/
position: relative;
top: 40px;
float: left;


}

#aboutmeright {

width: 450px;
height: 220px;
/*border: 1px solid #000;*/
position: relative;
top: 40px;
float: right;
}

.clear {

display: block;
clear: both;
```

}

Comment: may be this question can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769271/clear-right-also-does-clear-left-strange-floating-behaviour?rq=1#_=_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have your `sectiontwowrapper` div set to `position: relative` with `top: 100px`. That moves the whole section down 100 pixels - even though the clear works, the sectiontwowrapper is then 100px down into the next section.

Comment: Ah didn't spot that! Thanks a lot :)